# Blackberry Outage: How can I PIN a large number of users?

Tags: failover, disaster-recovery, blackberry

We lost power due to the hurricane and need to notify [BES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server) users that services will be restored soon.

How can I extract all BES users and send them a notification message?

Also how do I alter the from address that is sent?

Comment: I really want to edit the tags and add [hurricane]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export your list of users from the BES administration webpage, including the PIN.

Then you can [use the BlackBerry Enterprise Server Resource Kit to send PIN messages from a command line](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/11727/Send_a_PIN_message_BBUA_438582_11.jsp). A little bit of copy-and-paste in a batch file or a good `FOR` command can make this happen.

Of course, all of this depends on your BES server being online. But if you power is out, how is your BES server working but your email servers aren't?

Comment: We failed over to a new datacenter... so the mailbox rescan is taking a long long time